# jQuery set height of element

Tags: jquery

How do I set the inner div's height to it's parent using the each() method?

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="inner">Stuff</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="inner">Stuff</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="inner">Stuff</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="inner">Stuff</div>
</div>
```

This doesn't seem to work:

```
$('.box').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $inner = $this.find(".inner");
    $inner.height( $this.height );

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get element's height you have to use [**method**](http://api.jquery.com/height/) `height()`:

```
$('.box').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $inner = $this.find(".inner");
    $inner.height( $this.height() );
});
```